# retain white spaces in flextable

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

How can I retain the (additional) white space of a character column in a flextable? The code sequence

```
flextable(data.frame("temp" = c("Lore ips", 
                                "dol  sit")))
```

generates the following image:

[image]

Note how the "ips" and "sit" subtexts would be aligned in the `data.frame` but are not aligned in the flextable.

Comment: Maybe replacing spaces with `&nbsp;` will work.

Comment: fwiw I think you have two issues here: first is that flextable seems to eliminate extra spaces. 
But the second one is that the output font is not monospaced like your R code, which means that even retaining that space would not allow them to line up. Consider 

```flextable(data.frame("temp" = c("Lore ips",  "doll sit")))```
which definitely has the same number of characters, but comes out unaligned too.

Comment: thanks @mweylandt: in the application data I'm going to ignore the font issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White spaces are indeed collapsed in HTML output. You can use a tab instead:

```
flextable(data.frame("temp" = c("Lore ips", "dol\tsit")))
```

[image]

Or you can add extra css instruction (for the HTML output):

```
set_flextable_defaults(extra_css = ".tabwid{white-space: break-spaces;}")
flextable(data.frame("temp" = c("Lore ips", "dol   sit")))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this idea. I'm afraid that the tab will cover to many characters

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use a function to replace spaces with `&nbsp;` like this:

```
library(flextable)

render_cell <- function(x) {
  return(paste0("<td>", gsub(" ", "&nbsp;", x), "</td>"))
}

ft <- flextable(
  data.frame(
    temp = c(render_cell("Lore ips"), render_cell("dol  sit"))
  )
)
ft
```

Comment: unfortunately the html-tags are interpreted as text, producing the table with entries `<td>Lore&nbsp;ips</td>` and `<td>dol&nbsp;&nbsp;sit</td>`